# JTable is not displayed in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can't manage to display the JTable in a JFrame. Actually I have extracted the data from an ArrayList and filled the JTable row by row. I have checked that the JTable is filled, the number of rows is equal to the rows in the original ArrayList. Yet running the function shows a blank GUI. I really do not see the problem in my code:

```
public Graphicalinterface4() {
    //super (new GridLayout(1,0));

    //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    getdata2 in=new getdata2();
    try {
        ArrayList<Piece> test=in.getList();
        ArrayList<Piece> classified=in.classify(test);
        JTable table=getlocaltable(classified); 
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrPane=new JScrollPane(table);
        //scrPane.setSize(800,690);
        //scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.add(scrPane);

        //scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public JTable getlocaltable(ArrayList<Piece> in) {


    //new Object[]{"Type","Company","reference","description","price","To order"}));

    //DefaultListModel<Piece> testlst=new DefaultListModel<Piece>();
    int sz=in.size();
    String[] columns=new String[] {
            "Type","Company","reference","description","price","To order"
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    //JTable table=new JTable(null, in.toArray());
    for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) {
        Piece p=in.get(i);

        String type=p.gettype();
        String company=p.getasc();
        String reference=p.getref();
        String description=p.getdesc();
        String price=p.getprice();
        String image=p.getimage();
        System.out.println(type);
        //DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{type,company,reference,description,price,Integer.toString(0)});
    }
    JTable table=new JTable(model);
    System.out.println(table.getRowCount());
    return table;
}


static Graphicalinterface4 ssp;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {ssp=new Graphicalinterface4();}
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

You have 0 columns in the `TableModel`. The columns displayed is determined by the columns in the `TableModel`, not the number of items in each row. So adding rows of data has no effect.

Read the `DefaultTableModel` API for the proper constructor to use that will accept the "columns" variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I had not initialized the DefaultTableModel correctly. In the API the String[] and Object[][]{} are inverted(DefaultTableModel(String, Object[][]{}), but this works for me.

```
public JTable getlocaltable(ArrayList<Piece> in) {


    //new Object[]{"Type","Company","reference","description","price","To order"}));


    int sz=in.size();
    String[] columns=new String[] {
            "Type","Company","reference","description","price","To order"
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{}, columns);
    //JTable table=new JTable(model);
    for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) {
        Piece p=in.get(i);

        String type=p.gettype();
        String company=p.getasc();
        String reference=p.getref();
        String description=p.getdesc();
        String price=p.getprice();
        String image=p.getimage();
        System.out.println(type);
        //DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{type,company,reference,description,price,Integer.toString(0)});
    }
    JTable table=new JTable(model);
    System.out.println(table.getRowCount());
    return table;
}
```

Comment: `Thanks! I had not initialized the DefaultTableModel correctly.` - glad my suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" my answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know the problem has been solved. By the way that is NOT the best constructor to use. You can use the constructor that take the array of columns names along with a number of rows equal to 0. PLease reread the API.